# Python mutually dependent classes (circular dependencies)

Tags: python, class, circular-dependency

I've searched a lot, but what I find is mainly examples of recursive programming in python. So here goes the question:

How can I achieve this?

```
class A:
    b = B()

class B:
    a = A()
```

Comment: That's not recursion, it's a circular dependency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything is dynamic in Python - even the class declarations.  There's nothing to stop you modifying the contents of a class after the initial declaration:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    a = A()

A.b = B()
```

NB: If you're not that familiar with Python, the `pass` keyword simply allows you to say 'nothing here' - it's not important unless class A is as empty as it is in this example!

Comment: this also wouldn't work if you `from foo import A` in another file