# How do you deal with multiple Python classes in the same module depending on each other?

Tags: python, class, import

I'm using an ODM library and I'm defining documents as classes within the same module, when they are related. I've hit a circular dependency problem and because I haven't come across this before in Python, I don't know how to inform the classes of the existence of each other. Example:

```
''' docs.py '''
from mongoengine import Document
from mongoengine.fields import StringField, ReferenceField, ListField


class Base(Document):
    some_field      = StringField()


class Foo(Base):
    other_field     = StringField()
    another_field   = ReferenceField(Bar)


class Bar(Base):
    other_field     = StringField()
    another_field   = ListField(ReferenceField(Foo))
```

As it stands the Python will throw a `NameError` because `Bar` is not defined when the interpreter gets to a reference to it in the file, within the class `Foo`. How do I tell Python not to worry and that the class definition will be along shortly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python mutually dependent classes (circular dependencies)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402522/python-mutually-dependent-classes-circular-dependencies)

Comment: @ShawnChin: I don't think the solution in the linked question applies here, so it's not a real duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReferenceField` accepts class name as well.

```
another_field   = ReferenceField('Bar')
```

Comment: I didn't know that (doesn't mention it in the API docs), the approach of referencing `A.field = ReferenceField(B)` is probably more applicable to Python generally, but I think this approach is preferable here because it maintains readability in the module (all document fields grouped together) – Edwardr 9 secs ago edit