# How to define circularly dependent data classes in Python 3.7+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency, python-dataclasses

Suppose that `class A` has a member whose type is `class B`, and `class B` has a member whose type is `class A`.

In Scala or Kotlin, you can define the classes in any order without worries in this case because the firstly-defined class can use the secondly-defined class as usual, even in case/data classes.

However in Python, the following code

```
class A:
    b = B()

class B:
    a = A()
```

throws a compile error because `class B` is not defined when `class A` is being defined.

You can work around this simple case, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402522/python-mutually-dependent-classes-circular-dependencies)

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    a = A()

A.b = B()
```

However, this way does not work for data classes in Python because assigning members after the definition of data classes will not update the auto-generated methods of the data classes, which makes the usage of "data class" useless.

```
@dataclass
class A:
    b: B  # or `b: Optional[B]`

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A  # or `a: Optional[A]`
```

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I'm thinking of just closing this as a duplicate of [Type hints: solve circular dependency](//stackoverflow.com/q/33837918), because this is just another type hint circular dependency problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are several ways to solve circular dependencies like this, see [Type hints: solve circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837918/type-hints-solve-circular-dependency)

You can always apply the decorator manually (and update the annotations), like @Nearoo's answer shows.

However, it might be easier to "forward declare" the class:

```
class A:
    pass

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A

@dataclass
class A:
    b: B
```

Or simply use a forward reference:

```
@dataclass
class B:
    a: 'A'

@dataclass
class A:
    b: B
```

The cleanest is to import [Python 4.0's behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations) (if you can):

```
from __future__ import annotations

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A

@dataclass
class A:
    b: B
```

Comment: The `__future__` import is nice, but doesn't seem to work if you have to do something like `a: A = field=(default_factory=A)`. Is there something additional that can be done in this case or is forward declaring the only option?

Comment: Actually, looks like forward declaring doesn't work in this case either...

Comment: The `__future__` import works nicely with `@dataclass` in python 3.11

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your goal by applying the `dataclass` decorator only after we injected the field `b` into `A`. For that, we simply have to add the type annotation into `A`'s `__annotations__`-field

The following code solves your problem:

```
class A:
    b: None     # Note: __annotations__ only exists if >=1 annotation exists

@dataclass
class B:
    a: A

A.__annotations__.update(b=B) # Note: not the same as A.b: B
A = dataclass(A) # apply decorator
```

Concerning the safety and validity of this method, [PEP 524](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations) states that

> ..at the module or class level, if the item being annotated is a simple name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the __annotations__ attribute of that module or class.
>   [This attribute] is writable, so this is permitted:
>
> `__annotations__['s'] = str`

So adding a type annotation later on by editing `__annotations__` is identical to defining it at the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's even more verbose, but how about using a lambda for the field factory:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class A:
    b: B = field(default_factory=lambda: B())


@dataclass
class B:
    a: A = field(default_factory=lambda: A())


A()  # results in infinite recursion (as intended?)
```